# Why present perfect continuous in this sentence?

Tags: present-perfect

Why present perfect continuous in this sentence?

> Today, (Monday 1st July) at XXXXX we had a bit of a catch up on who we'**ve been watching** over the weekend at Glasto and listened to some jungle following what felt like hours of organ drones (or "Church music" as we've nicknamed it)

Why not had been watching as on Monday they (people working at XXXXX) were not in Glasto but back in their office.

Present perfect continuous could fit in the  case of they would plan to return to Glasto to see more concert this year but I checked the date of the festival and it  ended  yesterday (30th June) so it won't be possible for them to return to Glasto for this year.

So why present perfect continuous? (can't find any good reason)

Answer (score 1):

It could have been past perfect; but they are choosing to treat the watching as part of an extended activity that continues to the present.

Speakers often use a simple past or a present perfect when a past perfect would be possible, if that does not cause an ambiguity.

Comment: Even if the event has already finished ? Is this use colloquial ?

Comment: The perfect is used when the speaker is wishing to convey that the event described has some present relevance. What that present relevance is, can be very variable. As I said, the speaker is choosing to treat the event as part of a larger process that is still continuing: presumably, thinking of their reporting of Glasto.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is grammatically incorrect. If the event were still going on you could use the present perfect continuous, but it won't work when expressing the past. Simple past continuous: "Today, at XXXXX we had a bit of a catch-up on who we were watching over the weekend . . . . "